# How do I view photos in Dropbox that were saved as zip files?

Tags: dropbox

I have some Dropbox files that downloaded as `zip`, but they are actually photos and I can't view them.
How can I view them or save them in the Dropbox photo folder?

Answer (score 1):

Hope you downloaded your photos as zip.

Please note that you have uncompress utility like winrar in your machine to inflat the zipped files. If not Install the one and then check whether you can able to view the photos.

Also make sure you have installed any photo viewer in your machine. As a work around try to open the files in paint.

Also please note that it is not possible to view the zipped files in dropbox. you can download and unzip it in your local computer and then you can upload to your dropbox account(photo folder)

Hope this helps!